# Adding new user gives error "a value of type "const wchar_t" cannot be assigned to entity of type "LPWSTR""

Tags: c++, winapi

When I try to create user account in C++, I get the error

> a value of type "const wchar_t" cannot be assigned to entity of type "LPWSTR"

The error occurs twice with equal sign on both `usri1_name` and `usri1_password`.  Using Visual Studio 2019 to compile.  Any ideas?

```cpp
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib") //heard this is dynamic linking ?

#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>

int main()
{
    USER_INFO_1 ui;
    DWORD dwLevel = 1;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    //NET_API_STATUS nStatus;

    ui.usri1_name = L"istech";
    ui.usri1_password = L"p@ssword";
    ui.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
    ui.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    ui.usri1_comment = NULL;
    ui.usri1_flags = UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE;
    ui.usri1_script_path = NULL;

    NetUserAdd(NULL, dwLevel, (LPBYTE)&ui, &dwError);

}
```

Comment: Please copy'n'paste the error message. It include a code (Cxxxx) which you can use to look up explanations or locate similar questions here. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Use const_cast. Win32 interface is not well designed.

Comment: If you want to build unicode, use the right project settings, instead, and the defines should be handled for you in headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `usri_name` and `usri_password` fields are pointers to *non-const* Unicode buffers, but you are trying to assign string literals to them, which are *const* data.

So, you can either:

- `const_cast` away the const-ness of the literals (be extra careful with this!):

```cpp
ui.usri1_name = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"istech");
ui.usri1_password = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"p@ssword");
```

- copy the literals' content into local `wchar_t[]` arrays:

```cpp
wchar_t name[] = L"istech";
wchar_t pass[] = L"p@ssword";

ui.usri1_name = name;
ui.usri1_password = pass;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!!  Been mulling over this for a few days now.

Comment: You can't safely pass `const_cast`'ed pointer to an API that requires non-const: it may try to modify your string (for example, parse it using `strtok`, or change case). The fact that this particular function doesn't do it is a pure luck.

Comment: @VladFeinstein in general, yes. You have to use `const_cast` with extra care. However, a lot of older C APIs are simply not const-correct and will use pointer-to-non-const's even for readonly access. So more times than not, you can get away with this. But you really have to evaluate it on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing the solution, below is what works for me:

```
    USER_INFO_1 user_info;
    ZeroMemory(&user_info, sizeof(user_info));
    wchar_t name[] = L"istech"; 
    wchar_t pass[] = L"password";
    user_info.usri1_name = name;
    user_info.usri1_password = pass;
    user_info.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
    user_info.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT | UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD | UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE;

    DWORD dwLevel = 1;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus = NetUserAdd(NULL, dwLevel, (LPBYTE)&user_info, &dwError);
```